# Unable to use accessToken instead of idToken - msal python

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I am validating my Bearer token through JWT in Python and it was earlier written in a way to handle idTokens only. We just moved to the new auth code flow pattern on the UI and they advice me to use accessToken instead of idToken for token validation. The app works great E2E if I use idToken, however when I use accessToken in the Bearer auth, the validation fails. I get a 401 unauthorized.

Please advice.

Here is my python code:

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import time
import calendar
from functools import wraps
from jose import jwk, jwt, JWTError
from flask import abort, current_app, request
from src.database import db
from src.secrets import derive_base64_secret
from src.models.user import User, UserRoleEnum

CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID")
TENANT_ID = os.environ.get("AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID")
AUTHORITY_MSAL = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/v2.0"

OIDC = requests.get(f"{AUTHORITY_MSAL}/.well-known/openid-configuration").json()
MSAL_JWKS = requests.get(OIDC["jwks_uri"]).json()
S2S_JWK = {"alg": "HS256", "kty": "oct", "k": derive_base64_secret("S2S JWT", 32)}


def validate_msal_token(token):
    try:
        return jwt.decode(token, MSAL_JWKS, audience=CLIENT_ID, issuer=[AUTHORITY_MSAL])
    except JWTError:
        abort(401)


def validate_s2s_token(token):
    try:
        return jwt.decode(token, S2S_JWK, audience=CLIENT_ID, issuer=CLIENT_ID)
    except JWTError:
        abort(401)


def create_s2s_token(ttl, additional_claims):
    now = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())

    claims = {
        "iss": CLIENT_ID,
        "aud": CLIENT_ID,
        "iat": now,
        "exp": now + ttl,
        **additional_claims,
    }

    return jwt.encode(claims, S2S_JWK)


def get_access_token():
    authorization = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    if isinstance(authorization, str) and authorization.startswith("Bearer "):
        return authorization[7:]

    return request.args.get("access_token")

def load_user():
    access_token = get_access_token()

    if not access_token:
        abort(401)

    token = validate_msal_token(access_token)
    if not token:
        abort(401)

    oid = token.get("oid", None)
    if not oid:
        abort(403)

    user = User.query.filter_by(OID=oid).first()
    if not user:
        # Auto add the first user to access the API as an Admin IN DEVELOPMENT ONLY
        if current_app.env == 'development' and User.query.count() == 0:
            user = User(OID=oid, Display_Name="Unknown", User_Name="unknown@example.com", Role=0)
            db.session.add(user)
        else:
            abort(403)

    display_name = token.get("name", None)
    if display_name and user.Display_Name != display_name:
        user.Display_Name = display_name

    # `preferred_username` is supplied on a v2 id token as provided by the FM
    # `unique_name` is supplied on a v1 id token as provided by the MDA
    user_name = token.get("preferred_username", token.get("unique_name", None))
    if user_name and user.User_Name != user_name:
        user.User_Name = user_name

    db.session.commit()

    request.token = token
    request.user = user

    return user


def jwt_required(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        access_token = get_access_token()

        if not access_token:
            abort(401)

        token = validate_s2s_token(access_token)
        if not token:
            abort(401)

        request.token = token
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def user_required(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        load_user()
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your code. You should receive a response from the bearer auth and be granted access. It appears that your credentials are insufficient for successful authentication resulting in a 401 unauthorized. Based on the situation, perform a secondary check on the cause of failure. Token validation is not required for all apps. Apps should only validate a token in the following circumstances listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens). APIs and web apps can only validate tokens with an aud claim that matches their app; other resources may have their own token validation requirements. Learn more about managing access tokens [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/operationalize/how-to-manage-access-tokens#:%7E:text=If%20an%20authenticated%20user%20has%20a%20bearer%20token%27s,%27401%20-%20Unauthorized%20%28invalid%20credentials%29%27%20error%20is%20returned.).